# Search for a string within an array

Tags: c++

I am making a phonebook program for c++ and am having trouble transferring my search function into my main function. When I compile it and search for the name, it crashes the program.

Search Function:

```
int search(string name){
    for(int i=0; i<counter; i++){
        if(data[i][0] == name){
        return i;
        }
            else{
            cout << "Name not found" << endl;
            }
    }

}
```

Main Function:

```
int main(){
    bool done = false;
    int choice;
    string name;
    string areaCode;
    string number;

    load_contacts("contacts.txt");

    cout << "Welcome to AddressBook" << endl;

    while(!done){

        cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
        cout << "1) Display all contacts" << endl;
        cout << "2) Add a contact" << endl;
        cout << "3) Remove a contact" << endl;
        cout << "4) Search a contact" << endl;
        cout << "5) Exit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice){

            case 1:
            display_contacts();

            break;

            case 2: 
            add_contacts(name, areaCode, number);
            cout << "Contact Added!";
            cout << endl;


            break;

            case 3:
            cout << "Name to remove: ";
            cin >> name;  
            remove_contacts(name);          

            break;

            case 4:
            cout << "Name to search: ";
            cin >> name;
            search(name);

            break;

            case 5: cout << "Good bye." << endl;
            done = true;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give some details on how exactly it "crashes the program?"

Comment: The while loop in my main function just keeps repeating over and over again.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a crash.

Comment: Oh. Well I just don't see why it isn't preforming my search function. I am pretty new to programming and don't know if I'm missing something or if the coding is just simply wrong

Comment: What is `data`? Do not use global variables. What should `search` return if the element is not found?

Comment: data is just what I named the array. and I'm not sure what search should return. It should just output "Name not found"

Comment: Where is the array in your code? The function must return a value or throw an exception, or it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Must you implement your own search function?  There already exists an efficient one in the STL: [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: The array is in my add contacts function. And yes my professor wants us to create a search function for the program.

Comment: if(counter <100){
 string name;
 string areaCode;
 string number;
 cout << "Contact name: ";
 cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //(1000, '\n')
 getline(cin, name);
 cout << "Area code: ";
 cin >> areaCode;
 cout << "Number: ";
 cin >> number;

 
 data[counter][0]=name;
 data[counter][1]=areaCode;
 data[counter][2]=number;
 
 counter++;
 return true;
 }

Comment: You don't seem to have `counter` which might be an issue, check what is going on with counter first

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code you posted, mostly due to undefined variables being called.

**1:** For your search method, `counter` comes out of nowhere and is being used as a numeric limiter for the loop.

**2:** Also within your search method, the 2D array `data` is also undefined, unless it is a global variable set from the `load_contacts` method that isn't being shown, so currently you're searching a 2D array that doesn't exist.

**3:** Your `"Name not found"` message is in an `else` statement within the for loop in your method, therefore being executed every time a loop doesn't find the name. You may want to move that outside of the loop to print and then return an error number, maybe `-1` to handle later.

**4:** Your `search` method is a return type of `int`, however in your `main` you are not assigning the returned value to any variable to be used, so if there is a successful search, nothing will happen.

If I'm incorrect with any of these, please tell me, but I would focus on the obvious errors first to see if they are causing the crashing.